# Password manager with the ability to add notes

Tags: password-management

Obviously LastPass, KeePass, 1Password and alike are the solutions to look for when you are searching for a password manager.

I find myself in the situation that I have to maintain quite some accounts to hosting companies etc. which use usernames likes "w465adfa1d6" for login. I can´t change the login and I can´t use a mail address to log in.

Now, while all password managers won´t have a problem with those usernames, I can´t keep in my head which account links to which customer. I´d need the option to have another field, like a note or something, so I see that info when choosing the username to help me with filling out the login form.

Does any password manager bring something like this with him? Ideally something I could sync across devices.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought SU might be the right place, as there were lots of password manager questions around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In KeePassX the `Title` field is separate from the `Username` field and you can sort on any of the fields (including the Title and URL). There's also a freeform (and sortable) `Comments` field.

[image]

I can't imagine this is unique to KeePass.

Comment: This is not a product recommendation site. Please avoid answering requests for products which are off topic. You can point them to [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) where it is on topic.